# Install Ruby 2.3.2 on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows

I have an old Ruby 2.3.2 app I've been asked to help maintain on Windows 10. `RubyInstaller` (https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/archives/) would normally be great, but it seems like 2.3.2 was not ported over.

Since `RubyInstaller` was not an option, installing RVM on the Windows Subsystem for Linux was the next option. While this sometimes works, it has issues with our VPN pretty regularly, which seems like a recurring issue with WSL (https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1350 && https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/416).

Is there a way to convert any of the 2.3.2 builds (https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/11/15/ruby-2-3-2-released/) to run on windows?

Comment: I'm curious about the answer to this as well.

Comment: I guess the first question is why do you need that specific TEENY version rather than say `2.3.3` which was literally released 5 days later (which might explain the lack of port to windows)

Comment: I can look into that as well, but I'm new to Ruby so I don't know the differences yet.

Comment: From reading the release logs Ruby 2.3.3 just offers bug fixes over Ruby 2.3.2, so your code will run fine on Ruby 2.3.3 (If it was truly written on 2.3.2 and not an older version)

Comment: Yeah, that's the direction we're planning on going.